# WooCommerce - Category and Product Tags SEO - Google Punish?

Tags: wordpress, seo, woocommerce

I've got a little question about SEO, especially for Google.
In WooCommerce you can add a product to a category and you can also add Product Tags for a product.

So my question is, when I have a product, for example an Mercedes Car and I add it to the category "Mercedes" and to the the product tag "Mercedes", will Google punish my site for Keyword Spamming?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Probably not......but they might if all you have no other content on the page. There are plugins that will measure keyword density (only the text in `the_content()` ) but it gives you a idea of what is acceptable. But it hard to answer definitively on googles search algoritims, they keep them secret.

Answer (score 0):

No it won't. That's not considered as keyword stuffing or spanning.

You would need to mention long list of keywords like: blue mercedes, red mercedes, big mercedes, small mercedes, my mercedes, etc. on a page to trigger an issue.